# Failed building with Bazel on Windows

Tags: java, windows, bazel

When I try to build bazel based project on Windows, always see like this:

```
ERROR: Skipping 
'//tools/local_server/service:auth_service_java_grpc__do_not_ref                                                                                                                
': invalid target format 
'//tools/local_server/service:auth_service_java_grpc__d                                                                                                                
': target names may not end with carriage returns (perhaps the input source is CRLF-terminated)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I get the same error

Comment: Which bazel version do you use?